# Get the ID of inserted item if new, or the existing ID if it's not new

Tags: python, sqlite

Since the column `t` is `UNIQUE`, `foo` won't be inserted twice:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.execute("CREATE TABLE data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, t TEXT UNIQUE);")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO data(t) VALUES (?)", ("foo", ))
print(c.lastrowid)  # 1
c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO data(t) VALUES (?)", ("bar", ))
print(c.lastrowid)  # 2
c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO data(t) VALUES (?)", ("foo", ))
print(c.lastrowid)  # 2, how to get 1 instead, 
                    #    because "foo" already exists with ID=1?
```

**How to get the ID of the already-existing item in the last line instead of the ID of the previous successful insertion?**

Is it possible without an additional `SELECT` that would take additional time?

---

Note: this doesn't work either:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.execute("CREATE TABLE data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, t TEXT UNIQUE);")
c = conn.cursor()
for r in c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO data(t) VALUES (?) RETURNING *;", ("foo", )):
    print(r)
print(c.lastrowid)
for r in c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO data(t) VALUES (?) RETURNING *;", ("bar", )):
    print(r)
print(c.lastrowid)
for r in c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO data(t) VALUES (?) RETURNING *;", ("foo", )):
    print(r)
print(c.lastrowid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is the RETURNING clause for the INSERT statement. Please see docs for details https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html

Note, if you use INSERT OR IGNORE, nothing happens when conflict occurs and nothing is returned. You need to use the UPSERT syntax, to force a dummy update in case of a conflict to make sure you get the existing row back.

```py
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.execute("CREATE TABLE data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, t TEXT UNIQUE);")
c = conn.cursor()
for r in c.execute("INSERT INTO data(t) VALUES (?) ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET t=t RETURNING *;", ("foo", )):
    print(r)
for r in c.execute("INSERT INTO data(t) VALUES (?) ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET t=t RETURNING *;", ("bar", )):
    print(r)
for r in c.execute("INSERT INTO data(t) VALUES (?) ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET t=t RETURNING *;", ("foo", )):
    print(r)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it doesn't work (see my edited question at the end, in the third INSERT, the RETURNING doesn't do anything.

Comment: You need to use the UPSERT syntax. See your fixed code in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you @PChemGuy! Is there no "UPSERT" in Sqlite? Do we have to do `INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET ...` instead?

Comment: There is no a dedicated UPSERT statement in SQLite. In SQLite, UPSERT is implemented as  a "ON CONFLICT" clause to the INSERT statement. See this https://sqlite.org/lang_upsert.html. Please do not forget to vote/accept answer if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks @PChemGuy. Can we avoid to SET anything where there is a conflict? (here it's not needed) All we need is to "RETURN *", but not really SET anything.

Comment: The short answer is NO. You can have ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING, but this is the same is INSERT OR IGNORE. It does nothing and returns nothing. You should have a minimal overhead, if you use i=i for an integer field, if available.

Comment: Linked topic: https://sqlite.org/forum/info/a490a6b058261365